# Exception handling in Python Tornado

Tags: python, exception, tornado

I am trying to handle exception occurred in `AsyncClient.fetch` in this way:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext
from tornado import ioloop

def handle_exc(*args):
    print('Exception occured')
    return True

def handle_request(response):
    print('Handle request')

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()

with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exc):
    http_client.fetch('http://some123site.com', handle_request)

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and see next output:

```
WARNING:root:uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crchemist/python-3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/tornado-2.0-py3.2.egg/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 259, in cleanup
    yield
  File "/home/crchemist/python-3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/tornado-2.0-py3.2.egg/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 162, in __init__
    0, 0)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
Handle request
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to catch this exception at all? Seems like an exception doesn't get raised properly.

Comment: @Glaslos, No, I am not able to catch it :( .

Comment: I remember some exceptions happening during the usage of tornado which are hard to catch. Maybe have a look in some ongoing issues... Sorry, I haven't used Tornado in a while...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.fetch):

If an error occurs during the fetch, the HTTPResponse given to the callback has a non-None error attribute that contains the exception encountered during the request.
You can call `response.rethrow()` to throw the exception (if any) in the callback.

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext
from tornado import ioloop

import traceback

def handle_exc(*args):
    print('Exception occured')
    return True

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error is not None:
        with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exc):
            response.rethrow()
    else:
        print('Handle request')

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()

http_client.fetch('http://some123site.com', handle_request)
http_client.fetch('http://google.com', handle_request)

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

---

The message you're seeing on the console is only a warning (sent through `logging.warning`). It's harmless, but if it really bothers you, see the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module for how to filter it.

Comment: Specifically, `Tornado` records logs to the root handler. So you need to attach handlers/filters to the root if you want to suppress them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Tornado at all, but I gave a look and you simply can't catch exceptions that way. The exception is generated in the constructor of _HTTPConnection(), and most of the code in that constructor is already wrapped by a different stack context:

```
    with stack_context.StackContext(self.cleanup):
        parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(_unicode(self.request.url))
        [...]
```

So basically whenever an exception is generated there (gaierror in your example), it is caught already and handled through self.cleanup, that in turns generate a 599 response AFAICT:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def cleanup(self):
    try:
        yield
    except Exception, e:
        logging.warning("uncaught exception", exc_info=True)
        self._run_callback(HTTPResponse(self.request, 599, error=e,
                            request_time=time.time() - self.start_time,
                            ))
```

Not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. I also was looking at _Connection and cleaup, but it is internal code of tornado. As for me there should be some mechanism to catch exceptions like that in own code.

Comment: By looking at the way the code is structured, I don't think there is a way without patching Tornado.