# Python HTTP 599: Connection closed (Tornado)

Tags: python, tornado, http-error, connection-close

I'm getting this error:

> HTTP 599: Connection closed [E 130405 11:43:14 web:1031] Uncaught
>   exception GET /networks/1/sensors/1/alarm (127.0.0.1)

while executing the following code:

```
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext

def handle_exc(*args):
print('Exception occured')
return True

@tornado.gen.engine
def check_status_changes(netid, sensid):

    como_url = "".join(['http://131.114.52:44444/ztc?netid=', str(netid), '&sensid=', str(sensid), '&start=-5s&end=-1s'])

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

    if response.error is not None:
            print("Terzo")
            print response.error
            with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exc):
                response.rethrow()
    else:
        print('Handle request')

    for line in response.body.split("\n"):
                if line != "": 
                    #net = int(line.split(" ")[1])
                    #sens = int(line.split(" ")[2])
                    #stype = int(line.split(" ")[3])
                    value = int(line.split(" ")[4])
                    print value
                    yield value
                    return


class AlarmHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self, netid, sensid):
        self.lock_tables("read", ['devices'])
        status = self.db.get("SELECT status from devices \
                          WHERE id=%s AND network_id=%s", sensid, netid)
        print("Primo")
        print status

        try:
            periodic = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_status_changes(netid, sensid), 5000)
            value = periodic.start()
            print("Secondo")
            print value
        except:
            print("Quarto")
            periodic.stop()
            self.finish()
            return
        if value != status['status']:

            self.lock_tables("write", ['devices'])
            self.db.execute("UPDATE devices SET status=%s \
                             WHERE id=%s AND network_id=%s", value, netid, sensid)
            self.unlock_tables()
            self.notice("Status changed")
```

In the class `AlarmHandler` there is a periodic routine called `check_status_changes`. In this function, I obtain the error of the title when there's a response.error.

How can I set if error condition in order to return to the class and manage the situation? Thank you.

**OTHER INFORMATIONS**

If I do a screen of Tornado, I see this:

> Primo
>
> {'status': None}
>
> Secondo
>
> None
>
> Terzo
>
> HTTP 599: Connection closed
>
> Exception occured

so, I think the program close the connection before the exception is rethtow!

And in the html consolle I see this error:

> File "./wsn.py", line 226, in check_status_changes
>       for line in response.body.split("\n"): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are raising an exception:

```
if response.error:
        print("Terzo")
        print response.error
        raise Exception(response.error)
        return
```

This will be an `Uncaught Exception`. You should code this to handle the exception without raising an exception. E.g. log the error message and abort the database update.

Comment: Ok MattH I tried with this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623570/1353274 you give me in the python chat. I tried but the error it's the same... Searching in the Internet I've seen that there is a similar bug in a old Tornado version... could be my problem? How can I get my Tornado version? I edit however the question with your solution.